# How to make appear only boxes which contain the searched word - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, search

I shared my screenshot, I would like that when I write a keyword, for example "user", only the boxes containing "user" appears, and the other disappear.

I need the whole explanation. This is just a static html one page website, without any PHP or server side. Just would like to know if this "filtering" is feasible to be done and how.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ky4R4.png)

Comment: You might need to post some`html` here!

Comment: jQuery `contains` is what you are probably after.

Answer (score 2):

I thing you should start your search with something like this:

```
$( "containerClass" ).each(function() {
  var txt =$( this ).text();
  if( txt.includes(searchTerm))
  {$( this ).show();}
  else{$( this ).hide();}
});
```

just remember that includes is case sensitive.